# Display all values in MapServer layer

Tags: postgis, mapserver, mapfile, point

I have a MapServer map file that gets data from PostGIS tables. One of the tables holds several linestrings that I set as points in the map file. They show up based on the zoom-level in my map.

Is there any way that I can tell the map file to display all points from the table at the same time regardless of zoom-level?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found some kind of workaround. If I increase the Extent in the map-files' outputformat to a ridiculously high number; the linestrings will be rendered all at the same time. I increased it from the default 4096 to 393 216. I know this is a silly workaround.